# Home Page URL Routing

Tags: c#

I have done URL routing in my project.I have a problem with home page URL/ home page menu. When I click on  Home page menu the URL becomes **www.domain.com/home**.I want my home page url to be **www.domain.com** instead of **www.domail.com/home**

I have no idea how to setup this routing because ~/ isn't accepted in the route.

My code in global.asax file is:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapPageRoute("home", "home", "~/index.aspx");

    }
```

What change should I do in my existing code to get www.domain.com URL for home page instead of **www.domain.com/home**

Thanks

Comment: have you tried `routes.MapPageRoute("home", string.Empty, "~/index.aspx");`

Comment: @Satpal yes I have tried this. It is giving error "The resource cannot be found."